# Keystore password? Huh?

Tags: macos, google-cloud-platform, command-line-interface, gsutil

I am attempting to create a GCP Signed URL using instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-with-helpers). When I run the gsutil command to create my signed-url I am immediately prompted to enter my "Keystore password". So this:

```
gsutil signurl -d 10m my-private-key.json gs://my-storage-bucket/index.html
```

results in this:

```
Keystore password: [I enter a wrong password]
Encountered an error while refreshing access token. If you are using a service account,
please verify that the gs_service_key_file field in your config file(s), /Users/my-user/.boto, /Users/my-user/.config/gcloud/legacy_credentials/my-gcp-user-email/.boto, is correct.
```

To be frank I haven't the slightest what my keystore password is or even what keystore it is talking about. Is it a local Mac keystore? Is it a GCP keystore? Something else?

Any clues as to what keystore is being referenced or even how I might go about changing the password to something else are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what [the `signurl` documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/signurl) says:

> ```
> gsutil signurl [-c <content_type>] [-d <duration>] [-m <http_method>] \
>    [-p <password>] [-r <region>] keystore-file url...
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> gsutil signurl <private-key-file> gs://some-bucket/some-object/
> ```
>
> The signurl command uses the private key for a service account (the
>   '' argument) to generate the cryptographic signature
>   for the generated URL. The private key file must be in PKCS12 or JSON
>   format. If the private key is encrypted the signed url command will
>   prompt for the passphrase used to protect the private key file
>   (default 'notasecret'). For more information regarding generating a
>   private key for use with the signurl command please see the
>   Authentication documentation.

So, the first argument after `signurl`, which in your question is `my-private-key.json`, is the keystore. It contains a private key.

Usually we encrypt private keys so that they are harder to steal. So when you created `my-private-key.json`, you were probably asked for a passphrase, and the passphrase was used to encrypt the private key.

But `gsutil` needs to decrypt the private key before it can use it to sign your URL. So `gsutil` needs the passphrase that was used to encrypt the private key. You need to enter that passphrase at the `Keystore password:` prompt. If you don't remember the passphrase you used to create the private key, then you will need to create a new private key.

(Perhaps the passphrase is in fact “notasecret”?)

Comment: Thanks Rob. There was no passphrase given by me and 'notasecret' was indeed one of my attempted passwords - but the result is the same. However after reading your answer I'm beginning to think my initial key creation may be suspect. I'll try fresh with a new key tomorrow and see how it goes.